# Windows 10 application issues. Start and Cortana freeze

Tags: powershell, windows-mobile, windows-10, windows, windows-10-desktop

Recently forced upgraded to windows 10 by microsoft. Windows Start and cortana froze. Searched google and from powershell ran

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach 
{Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Now lot of my windows application have disappeared. They show up with @{AppPackageName} in taskmanager or when searched using cortana for example @{Microsoft.ZuneMusic_2019.6.15131.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe}. I can not remove these app using any command like

[image: Command to remove application package]

Tried to install store app manually and get error Merge Failure : error 0x80070003 : Cannot register the Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.21.25.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe package because there was a merge failure with the following file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.21.25.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe\resources.pri

Full log below:
[image: Windows Store add-appxpackage failure]

Now I understand that store app is not getting add because add process is causing error or merge failure with another package (?). The problem is get/Add-AppxPackage are resolving dependency of application with package-version: Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1510.13020.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbw‌​e 
AND/OR 
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1510.13020.0_neutral_split.language-hi_8wekyb3d8bbwe

My laptop c:\program files\windowsapp only has Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1510.9020.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe (not diff in version 13020 and 9020). **Note**: The version no on app is 13020 but dependent package on drive is 9020.

Second package is missing from drive (Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1510.13020.0_neutral_split.language-hi_8wekyb3d8‌​bbwe).

How to get my calculator and windows store application back.

Comment: Now I can understand that issue is with dependency files versioning for the app. However dependencies files are not listed in app manifest then where?

Comment: I wrote a detailed blog [here explaining the problem in greater detail](http://blog.cloudjini.com/2015/11/wrong-dependency-package-getting.html).

Answer (score 0):

<1>Create a new user account and Log into the new account

<2>You can also try

Running the System File Checker by running

sfc /scannow

Download files from Windows Update to replace the corrupt ones by running

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Comment: creating new user account fix the problem for me and i had to delete old user account

Comment: Tried SFC/DISM, ran fine -no issues. I don't think they are problem... Problem is with microsoft's add-appxpackage and how it's resolving dependencies. anyone with good windows app development can comment.

May be new account uses different script/method for deployment of apps. Microsoft should be paying us for making us forced beta tester for there so called released product.

Comment: i try many option but creating new user account was only solution that worked . Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach 
{Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"} created more problem for me

Comment: In my case, The problem is get/Add-AppxPackage are resolving dependency of application with package-version:  
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1510.13020.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe AND/OR *.language-hi_8wekyb3d8bbwe

My laptop c:\program files\windowsapp only has Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1510.9020.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe (not diff in version 13020 and 9020). The version no on app is 13020 but dependent package on drive is 9020. 

Second package is missing from drive (Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1510.13020.0_neutral_split.language-hi_8wekyb3d8bbwe).

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following, at your own risk.

I had the same issue after trying to reinstall the apps via that powershell thingy. Fixed it and returned the apps to their out-of-box state by first wiping everything from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps and C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Packages and then reinstalling Windows over itself from the tech bench ISO (from under Windows and keeping "traditional" apps and files in place, of course). I had to use the ISO because the media creation tool wasn't cooperative at all, throwing some error at me. Just in case, the aforesaid wiping didn't cripple the vitals like the immersive control panel or something else, just the typical no start menu/dead modern apps/no right click on the taskbar items.

By the way, the whole problem started after the 1511 update. Modern apps would refuse to remember their settings, and windows shell experience host would freeze for no reason, taking the start menu and things like volume control with it. I've had this Windows installation for a couple of years now, and the system has gone pretty smoothly through the 8.0-8.1-10 update process over that time, but that 1511 screwed something big time.